# Is there a way to split the Chrome Ominbox into sections?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

Is there a way to split the Chrome Ominbox into sections?

I would like to split the omnibox into 3 sections, which each section of the omibox searching different sources. It would look something like this:

[image: Example::]

So if I tabbed over from the default URL section, it would go to my first red box, then another tab would go to the next red box. Each box would search a different url, like google.com, bing.com, duckduckgo.com etc.

I know I can add an extension that pops up new search bars, but I would really like to embed this functionality into the URL bar.

Comment: You can edit your question to put additional in there.

Comment: Not sure about splitting. But, with any [configured search engines](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95653?hl=en), you can type the URL (e.g., `bing.com`) and `Tab`, then enter your query. Also, this isn't really a programming question and would probably be a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Voting to migrate.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to cut down on all of the keystrokes... and because chrome stores searches... lets say that i have searched bing into google... when i type "b" into url bar, "Bing google search" comes up first, then "Bing.com" .. so I type, b, then tab to go to the bing google search, then tab to go the bing.com, then tab, which  bings the [bing.com:] search option in the url, then i can type the thing i want to search and hit enter and search. ... This functionality is not necessary by any means, but I think it would be very cool to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the layout of the Chrome location bar using an extension.

As some commenters have already noted, Chrome already supports multiple search engines using prefixes.